# Issue with case-insensitive regex pattern for re.sub()

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, case-insensitive

I am doing a dictionary manipulation using regex in Python.I want to remove `1dc.com` or `1DC.com` or `1dc.COM` or `1DC.COM` from a dictionary item.

Example Dictionary -

```
{'system_name': 'a1pvdb092', 'fdc_inv_sa_team': 'X2AIX_GBS'}
{'system_name': 'W00000001.1DC.com', 'fdc_inv_sa_team': 'LAA.BRAZIL.AAA.WINDOWS\n'}
{'system_name': 'a10000048', 'fdc_inv_sa_team': 'X2AIX_NSS'}
{'system_name': 'a10000049', 'fdc_inv_sa_team': 'X2AIX_NSS'}
```

Expected Output -

```
['a1pvdb092']
['W00000001']
['a10000048']
['a10000049']
```

Script -

```
import re
from opswareConnect import data

for row in data:
    arg1 = [row["system_name"],]
    arg1 = re.sub('[.1DC.com]\\b', '', str(arg1))
    print arg1
```

Output from the script -

```
['a1pvdb092']
['WBPVAP001Dco']
['a10000048']
['a10000049']
```

Comment: But `[.1DC.com]` is a *character group*...

Comment: removing `[]` should work , change to `re.sub('.1DC.com\\b', '', str(arg1))`

Comment: It worked! Thank you @WillemVanOnsem :)

Answer (score 6):

## Regex

The regular expression is `\.1dc\.com`.  The backslash escapes the dot which normally matches any character rather than just a period.

Make the search case insensitive with the [*re.IGNORECASE*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE) flag.

Find and eliminate the target expression using [*re.sub()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.sub).

## Full solution

```
import re

data = [
    {'system_name': 'a1pvdb092', 'fdc_inv_sa_team': 'X2AIX_GBS'},
    {'system_name': 'W00000001.1DC.com', 'fdc_inv_sa_team': 'LAA.BRAZIL.AAA.WINDOWS\n'},
    {'system_name': 'a10000048', 'fdc_inv_sa_team': 'X2AIX_NSS'},
    {'system_name': 'a10000049', 'fdc_inv_sa_team': 'X2AIX_NSS'},
]

for row in data:
    sysname = row['system_name']
    print([re.sub(r'\.1dc\.com', '', sysname, flags=re.IGNORECASE)])
```

## Output

```
['a1pvdb092']
['W00000001']
['a10000048']
['a10000049']
```

Comment: Fixed.  Thanks for noticing.